# How to launch an application in Blackberry simulator through command prompt

Tags: blackberry, command-prompt, blackberry-simulator

I want to open the simulator, load the cod file and run the application in Blackberry simulator through the command prompt.

I'm able to open and load the file to the simulator using fledgecontroller commands, but not able to launch the application. Could anybody please tell me how to launch the application from cmdpmpt ? Is there any fledgecontroller cmd for the same ? Please advise.

Thanks in advance..!!

Comment: AFAIK no. But check it yourself. Type `fledge /controller-help` in command line.

Comment: I did check the fledge/controller-help, but didn't find any useful commands... :-(

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky question.

You have three options:

1. Should work 100% - Make your app autostart. If you're using [bb-ant-tools](http://bb-ant-tools.sourceforge.net/docs) search for **runonstartup** parameter. Don't forget to wait in application until 'device' is fully powered up (`ApplicationManager.inStartup()`)
2. Not 100% working - Put the app position to jad file on home screen and after say fledge to  navigate to specific position on home screen and tap it. If you're using [bb-ant-tools](http://bb-ant-tools.sourceforge.net/docs) search for **ribbonposition** parameter. But this is valid for simulator version less than 6. I think system ignores it for 6+ OS
3. Didn't try myself yet - Start search and type application name and same steps with navigation from previous case

Are you trying to setup acceptance tests?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.... Let me try the second option that you have mentioned. Do you have any link/docs explaining the process....Can you please share it for making my life easier..

For the first option, we'll need to have separate builds for prod and test environments as auto start-up is not needed in actual purpose.
Yes, this is for setting up tests..

Comment: I'm not able to make the application loaded focusable and then click it to open. Can you provide more help on this...?

Comment: But I'm confused on how to navigate to a specific position. We can just swipe through the screen/make key press events/touch press the screen etc....but can we focus on to that specific location ?

Comment: No we can't. You have to know position of up and use up/down and left/right keys to navigate to the application